# Standalone .NET memory profiler

Tags: windows-7, .net, visual-studio, memory-management

I am looking for .NET memory profilers

- running on Windows 7 SP1 or higher
- can be commercial software
- must provide "per developer" license (not machine specific)
- must be able to run without Visual Studio (standalone profiler)
- support for .NET 2.0 and higher
- price < 600 €
- demo version available

Optional:

- provide a Visual Studio plugin

I already have JetBrains Resharper Ultimate and I'd like to compare it against other tools regarding performance impact and analysis speed.

Answer (score 1):

Something a little bit out of the box is to consider installing [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and use its [Profiler](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/) & [Heapshot](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/heapshot/).

- Standalone Profiler **No**
- running on Windows 7 SP1 or higher **Yes - *Cross Platform***
- Can be commercial software **Various [licencing](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/licensing/) options are available**
- must provide "per developer" license (not machine specific)
- must be able to run without Visual Studio (standalone profiler) - **Yes & Nearly**
- support for .NET 2.0 and higher - **Mono has its own equivalent but since the recent open sourcing of .NET integration [efforts are underway](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/dotnet-integration/) to integrate the codebases**
- price < 600 € **0.00 < 600** *Price starts at Free but a commercial licence is available where required.*
- demo version available **Just use the free version.**
- provide a Visual Studio plugin **No Mono provides a VS replacement [Mono Develop IDE](http://www.monodevelop.com/)**

If it isn't already you would need to make your code Mono compatible probably by using the [Mono Develop IDE](http://www.monodevelop.com/) *(also free)* but it is relatively simple to maintain a single codebase.  This would have the side effect of making your C# applications Linux and Mac OS X compatible *which is **usually** a very good thing*.

### Heapshot Screenshot

[image]

### Mono Develop Screenshot

[image]

*Disclaimer - I have no affiliation with the Mono Project or their sponsors [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/).*

Answer (score 0):

Redgate ANTS Performance & Memory profilers are way above and beyond the competition. They provide a quick and usefull data from your app. It is not cheap, but you can get a trial version.

Some editions of VS have built-in profilers, but they are notably less convenient and can barely work on large apps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. On this site (in contrast to other SE sites), answers should specifically mention how the requirements are met, e.g. by posting a serious link to the vendor and citing some sentences to proof the validity of the answer.